# Logic of Truthfulness

Tags: logic

I thought of this myself and could not begin to think of a solution without becoming confused:
There are two people, A and B.
A says, "B is telling the truth."
B says, "A is lying."
Are both lying or telling the truth? Or is one lying and the other telling the truth?

Comment: [Relevant wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox), see variation D under "Explanations and variants"

Comment: Or neither.  The is a variation of the Liar's Paradox or the Epimendies paradox (google it).  It ties closely with Godels incompleteness theorem (although that is an *extreme* over simplification.)  But basically the statements do not refer to any objective statement but instead only refer to each other circularly. Thus there is no fundamental meaning upon which to evaluate the truth of.

Comment: Anyway... No, they are not both telling the truth.  They are not both lying.  It is not the case that A is lying and B is telling the truth.  It is not the case that A is telling the true and B is lying.  All four of those are demonstrably impossible as you have figured out. As all are impossible it seems not all words that can be strung together into a sentence must be true or false.

Comment: One example I found illuminating was a chapter in Raymond Smullyan's "What is the name of this book?".  He had a chapter on wto box makers one who always carved true statments on his boxes and one who carved lies and a portrait placed in one of two boxes that have statements about which box has the portrait. He has a series of logic puzzle and final puzzle was a tricky logic puzzle where was logically proven that portrait was in the left box.  And the portrait was in the right box. WHAT HAPPENED? Answer: she physically put to portrait in the right box. Logical statements can't force reality.

Answer (score 1):

This is a version of a liar paradox similar to the [card paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_paradox). You can find logical contradictions in all possibilities of A or B lying or telling the truth.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought of this myself and could not begin to think of a solution without becoming confused:

There is a reason for that.   It is okay.

> > There are two people, A and B.
> >
> > - A says, "B is telling the truth."
> > - B says, "A is lying."
>
> Are both lying or telling the truth? Or is one lying and the other telling the truth?

We shall consider a "lie" to be a deliberately false statement, and that somehow both people know what the other said before making their own statement, contrary to the concept of temporal causality.   (Perhaps these people always tell the truth, or always tell a lie?)

These statements given can then be represented as

- $A\leftrightarrow B$ "if and only if A is truthful, then B is truthful."
- $B\leftrightarrow \neg A$ , "if and only if B is truthful, then A is truthless."

So therefore they are not consistent.   From such an inconsistent set of premises, your conclusions will be vacuous.

Also, I am lying.  This sentence is false.